# How to stop a timer from a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uibutton

The code below is a timer. After 3 seconds, I would like the user to have the ability to turn off the timer. I tried to explain what I was trying to do in the commented out section — I tried what I commented out but it did not work. I would like to keep the code the same, I just need to find a way to stop the timer using the UIButton `i`.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var i: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var u: UILabel!

    var time = 0
    var timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
        b()
    }

    func action() {
        time += 1
        u.text = String(time)
        if time == 2 {
            u.alpha = 0   
        }
        else if time > 3 {
            u.alpha = 0.5

               //  if i.isSelected{
                 //  timer.invalidate}
        }
        else {
            return
        }
    }
    func b(){
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

- Declare the timer as optional

  ```
  var timer : Timer?
  ```
- Replace the `IBAction start` with

  ```
  @IBAction func start(_ sender: AnyObject) {
      if timer == nil {
         b()
      } else {
         timer?.invalidate()
         timer = nil
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: No point checking for `nil`, *not* binding, then using conditional chaining. http://pastebin.com/Nghur9XK

Comment: Probably need to use `invalidate()` and not just `invalidate`. Doesn't the compiler give you a warning for this?

Comment: @vadian this work however button i is does not cause the timer to stop. The start button is what causes the timer to start stop. I would like button i to cause the timer to stop.

Comment: I was assuming that `button i` is the start button and is connected to the `IBAction`. If not use another `IBAction` with the code only in the `else` clause.

Comment: @vadian how would I write the else clause. Thanks

Comment: Just the two `timer` lines between the curly braces.